# Stripping out unwanted embed code

Tags: php, iframe, embed

I am currently looking at a piece of code for a friend and I am trying to strip out a piece of unwanted code but not sure how I can achieve what I want.

CODE:

```
<?php

$blah = '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/82444237" width="500" height="281"
 frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> 
<p><a href="http://vimeo.com/82444237">KING OF THE BEASTS</a> from 
<a href="http://vimeo.com/deltoidjohn">John Wiley</a> on 
<a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>';


echo($blah);
?>
```

In this code the website is showing: `from  on`

I want the start point of the input to be iframe and the endpoint to be /iframe.

Without manually making sure the iframe only is selected, any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: A simple `substr` with `strpos` should do the trick.

Comment: It wont, the links aren't always the same in length.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You'd apply it individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function blah($postTag)
{

//TERMINATES THE STRING AT </IFRAME>
$exploder = explode("iframe",$postTag);

//CALLS THE STRING UNTIL THE FIRST IFRAME INPUT AND CLOSES THE IFRAME TAG
$cleaned =  "<iframe".$exploder[1]."iframe>";

return $cleaned; 
}

$blahblah = blah('<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/82444237" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/82444237">KING OF THE BEASTS</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/deltoidjohn">John Wiley</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>');
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple [**`strstr()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) will do the job.

```
<?php
$blah = '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/82444237" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/82444237">KING OF THE BEASTS</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/deltoidjohn">John Wiley</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>';
echo strstr($blah,'</iframe>',true)."</iframe>";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/82444237" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: This isn't returning anything I'm afraid!

    </head>
<body>  
  </iframe></body>

</html>

Comment: Yes.
Definitely stripping out the start of the of the string.

Comment: Can you try in some other browser ? Works fine for me on Firefox & Chrome.

Comment: I've tried both of these browsers and get the following code:

</head>
<body>  
</iframe>
</body>
</html>

Comment: <?php
  

 //BLOG POST INPUT HERE
 $x = '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/82444237" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/82444237">KING OF THE BEASTS</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/deltoidjohn">John Wiley</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>';
 
 //TERMINATES THE STRING AT </IFRAME>
 $i = explode("</iframe>",$x);
 
 //CALLS THE STRING UNTIL THE FIRST IFRAME INPUT AND CLOSES THE IFRAME TAG
 echo ($i[0]."</iframe>");

  ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$blah = '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/82444237" width="500" height="281"  frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a  href="http://vimeo.com/82444237">KING OF THE BEASTS</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/deltoidjohn">John Wiley</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>';

echo substr($blah, 0, strpos($blah, '</iframe>')) ."</iframe>";
```

Output:

`<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/82444237" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>`